# Problemas de rendimiento en un NumberPicker

Tags: java, android

Tengo un `NumberPicker` que carga aproximadamente 6000 registros. Al probarlo en la `api > 20` su respuesta no es mas de 2 segundos pero al probarlo en una `api < 19` su respuesta es de 15 segundos o mas.

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de mejorar el tiempo de respuesta de la `api < 19` muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Diego, esto probando en Emulador.

Comment: hola he probado en 4 dispositivos físicos dos con 5.0 y el resultado es favorable pero al probarlo en dos celulares con api 16 y 17 el resultado es malo

Comment: No puedo asegurar que el rendimiento es malo con dispositivos con API < 20 pero podría ser más lenta la carga, si los dispositivos son de gama baja que tu dispositivo de API > 20, el cual probablemente tiene hasta un Quadcore!, que te parece si agregas el código con el que cargas los datos a tu NumberPicker?

Comment: No sé si un NumberPicker sea la solución para lo que estás tratando de hacer, son demasiados registros para que un usuario seleccione.

Comment: Has probado en usar un recyclerview si va igual de mal? porque google ha añadido funcionalidad snap a los recyclerview que podría ser un sustituto ya que los datos solo se cargan los justos.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a usar:

```
mainView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Y esto

```
android:layerType="hardware"
```

Eso fuerza la renderización por hardware y obliga a la GPU a hacer el trabajo de dibujado. Ya nos comentarás si te ha funcionado o no.